# Is there a good way to use arguments with message.content.includes in Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make a simple command were (For example) I could say "I'm bored" and it would say "Hi bored, I'm a bot!".

Here is what I have so far, I'm wondering how I can make that possible.

```
client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('bot')) {
    message.channel.send('https://media.giphy.com/media/tczJoRU7XwBS8/giphy.gif');
}
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(`i'm`)) {
    message.channel.send(`Hello ${args}, I'm a bot!`)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this with `String.includes()`, but it would be *way* easier to achieve this with `String.match()` (which works similar, but can actually return what was found) and Regex. Regex is used to match patterns in text, and you're absolutely looking for a general pattern here: "I'm {something}".

Here's one way of doing it using `match()` and regex, if you want to include spaces:

```
if(message.content.match(/(i'm )(.+)/i) && !message.author.bot) {
    message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.content.match(/(i'm )(.+)/i)[2]}, I'm a bot!`)
}
```

Here's a way to do it without including spaces, *which is probably what you want*:

```
if(message.content.match(/(i'm )(\w+)/i) && !message.author.bot) {
    message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.content.match(/(i'm )(\w+)/i)[2]}, I'm a bot!`)
}
```

I'll explain the regex within `match()`: parentheses indicate specific groups to match, `.` indicates any single character, `+` indicates one or more of the specified character(s), and the `i` flag represents making the match case insensitive (making `toLowerCase()` no longer required). You can go to websites like [this one](https://regex101.com/) for more information and to mess around with regex yourself.

In the first example, if you say "I'm a human" the bot responds with "Hello a human, I'm a bot!" (uses all args starting with the second one).
In the second example, if you say "I'm a human" the bot responds with "Hello a, I'm a bot!" (uses only the second arg).

Comment: For some reason it spams `Hello I'm , I'm a bot!` when I say `I'm sad`

Comment: @Kc5f, I've now fixed that issue in my answer. The answer now works (tested and works). It no longer spams, and it now says `Hello sad, I'm a bot!` as intended.